# Efficiently calling Paclet Repository functions

Tags: keyboard, paclets

I'm starting to explore the new [Wolfram Language Paclet Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/) and have a question about using these new functions efficiently.  The documentation and examples in [Bob Sandheinrich's Community post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2533977) all show functional calls like this
[image]
with the explanation that this is a typeset form of `PacletSymbol`.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for this typeset form? Is the only benefit that it downloads & loads the package? (it seems we can just call `CodeEquivalentQ` after loading the package)